# How to run game that needs administrator privilege as a standard user?

Tags: windows-7, security, administrator

I have a Windows 7 32 bit PC. Since my small kids use it, to prevent them from changing the Registry or anything dangerous like installing games containing malware, I've created a "Standard user" for them and kept an administrator account for me (protected with a password).

- I also disabled many settings for them (standard user) like accessing registry editor.
- Everything works fine but I installed a game for them "Red Alert 2"; this game needs `Administrator privilege`. Which mean whenever I try to open it from a standard user session it doesn't open and no message I get. Also if I right click on it and select `run as administrator` It asks me the credentials of Administrator's account but after entering the credentials it still doesn't work.
- I also set it in compatibility mode, but it still doesn't work.
- The thing that matters me is not just running this game which needs elevation from a standard user. Also I wonder Why I am asked to enter an administrator password after all the administrator wants to keep the password secret???!!!!
- Also I need some way that I save the Admin credentials for that application in a way the standard user can run it without knowing the Admin Credentials. Thank you!

Comment: Was the game already installed when you created the account for your kids? If so, it's possible that the game was only installed for the original account instead of for all users.

Comment: Actually, even if it was installed afterward it still could have been installed only for one account.

Comment: @RWW: In fact I've installed it on Administrator account then I added a standard user. So do you mean reinstalling it on a standard user will works?

Comment: It might. Games, especially games, shouldn't be asking for admin just to run.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia: I don't know why but I am sure it asks me admin privilege. that is because maybe to access system files.

Comment: @AdamMenz based on your comment I'll add what I asked and additional info as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oftentimes programs, especially games, will ask if the installation is for just one user on the system it is being installed on or for all users.  If you installed the game when you had one account, then added another account later, the game might not recognize the later account as an authorized user, even with admin credentials. The way to overcome this is to resinstall the game and make sure the "all users" option is checked if it asks.

Comment: Thank you. I've uninstalled it from my admin account and reinstalled it on the standard user. Now it works fine without asking any elevation.

Comment: Thank you again. Because I already faced another problem: I was managing a Cybercafe so for the reason that I don't wanted clients to mess up with system settings so I set up a standard user for them in each computer. But as you know after I installed Easycafe Client on each client machine on administrator account it doesn't work in clients machines after disabling administrator for them replacing it with a standard one. Now I tried it again (uninstalled it from admin account and installed it on standard account) it works like a charm! thanx again.

Comment: @AdamMenz anytime, glad I could help!